# what are Classes in Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, class, object

I dont understand why in javascript a class is called a class, when all it is is defining a function so that when it is ran it turns it into an object. 
Example the following.

```
var Person = function (firstName) {
  this.firstName = firstName;
  console.log('Person instantiated');
};


var person1 = new Person('Alice');
var person2 = new Person('Bob');

// Show the firstName properties of the objects
console.log('person1 is ' + person1.firstName); // logs "person1 is Alice"
console.log('person2 is ' + person2.firstName); // logs "person2 is Bob"
```

So is it just like a blueprint/template for an object?

EDIT. Ok I understand what I wrote is not a class now, on this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript it references that it is a class many times.

EDIT this question has been answered, thanks for your help people.

Comment: That isn't a class, that is what is referred to as a "constructor function". The model you have above is known as "pseudo-classical inheritance" because it mimics the way objects are created in languages with classes.

And no, they aren't blueprints/templates for an object because you can add on fields/methods to an object in JavaScript at any given time.

Comment: thanks for the hellp, didnt know that

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript

- this entire page refers to what i was talking about as a class

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript classes were recently introduced in `ECMAScript 6`. They are syntactic sugar over the previous `prototypal inheritance` model.

This allows for a simpler and cleaner syntax for creating objects and dealing with inheritance.

One way to declare a class is with the `class` keyword followed by the name of the class you're creating. Here's a simple example.

```
class Polygon {
  constructor(height, width) {
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
  }
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

It's important to note that classes are not supported in `Internet Explorer` or `Opera`.

Answer (score 0):

Classes are technically just a form of function introduced in EcmaScript 6. They require either a **class declaration** or a **class expression** *prior* to any uses of the class. However, the syntax used in your example is not either of these things. Examples of class usage can be found at [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes).

Comment: I got this from the Mozilla site. "The class

JavaScript is a prototype-based language and contains no class statement, such as is found in C++ or Java. This is sometimes confusing for programmers accustomed to languages with a class statement. Instead, JavaScript uses functions as constructors for classes. Defining a class is as easy as defining a function. In the example below we define a new class called Person with an empty constructor."